How to make a Bootstrap 5 navbar dropdown menu open on hover on desktop but on click on mobile?
I'm kinda new to the whole Web Dev side of things, so i need some help 
I've been making a Wordpress website for a company and, while doing the navbar using Bootstrap 5, i noticed that my CSS is breaking the functionality of the whole thing.
The CSS does what i wanted on Desktop: dropdown menus open on hover and the items inside the dropdown menu are perfectly clickable. The thing is, i wanted them to open ONLY on hover, but they're still clickable and will remain open if clicked.
Also, my CSS completely broke the mobile functionality, so the WHOLE menu won't even open on mobile, the button toggler won't function and I'm at a loss here, don't really know how to solve it or where to go from this.
If i remove this styling from the CSS file, the navbar functions as it would out of the box, so no hover, but it can be clicked on mobile also, so i know it's the styling that's breaking it.
Any solutions are welcome, including using scripts and such. Thanks :)
CSS (style.css):
.navbar-wrapper {
    background-color: var(--orange);
}
.nav-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 90rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2.5rem;
    height: 5.625rem;
}
.navbar-toggler {
    border-style: none;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: .85rem;
}
.collapse.navbar-collapse {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    display: flex;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: .625rem 0.75rem;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
.nav-item {
    padding-left: .625rem;
}
.nav-item.active .nav-link{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    color: var(--orange) !important;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #fff;
}
.nav-item.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: var(--light-grey);
    transition: color 0.3s;
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover {
    color: var(--orange);
}

PHP (header.php):
<header class="navbar-wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <div class="container-lg padding-global nav-container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/') ); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/svg/logo.svg" width="130px" height="auto" alt="Logo Bigdooh">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Menu de Navegação', 'your-theme-slug' ); ?>">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array( 
                    'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                    'depth' => 2,
                    'container' => 'div',
                    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id' => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                    'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
                    'fallback_cb' => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker' => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
                ) ); 
                ?>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>


You can simply add CSS media query in your CSS to only have the additional CSS work on the desktop and not on mobile.
@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    .navbar-wrapper {
        background-color: var(--orange);
    }
    .nav-container {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 90rem;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 2.5rem;
        height: 5.625rem;
    }
    .navbar-toggler {
        border-style: none;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        padding-top: .85rem;
    }
    .collapse.navbar-collapse {
        justify-content: flex-end;
        display: flex;
    }
    .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: .625rem 0.75rem;
        border-radius: 50px;
        transition: background-color 0.3s;
    }
    .nav-item {
        padding-left: .625rem;
    }
    .nav-item.active .nav-link{
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        color: var(--orange) !important;
    }
    .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
        color: #fff;
    }
    .nav-item.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: var(--light-grey);
        transition: color 0.3s;
    }
    .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover {
        color: var(--orange);
    }
}

You can copy the above CSS code and it should solve the problem you are having.
